# How to set up proxy details in pythonanywhere for cloudinary

Tags: python, flask, cloudinary, pythonanywhere

My flask app uploads images to cloudinary. It works fine in localhost but has connection errors in pythonanywhere. I have found out that the solution is setting up a proxy which I don't know how to do. I have tried this but it still doesn't work.

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(form.post_image.data, proxy = "http://proxy.server:3128")
```

I wish to know how this should be done. With an example, please.

Comment: What error did you get when you used the code above?  Was it still a 403 forbinner error?  Or something else?

Comment: I got this error: 

   ` cloudinary.api.Error: Unexpected error - MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.cloudinary.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1_1/*********/image/upload (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f740bc53668>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))",)`

Comment: Could you try upgrading urllib3?

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work for me in my django app

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and it was resolved by writing this exact same code snippet.

```
import cloudinary
cloudinary.config(
  cloud_name = config('CLOUD_NAME'),
  api_key = config('CLOUD_API_KEY'),
  api_secret = config('CLOUD_API_SECRET'),
  api_proxy = "http://proxy.server:3128"
)
import cloudinary.uploader
import cloudinary.api
```

Comment: I don't why but the order of import and config is important.